# What is the effect of using lower Cat# cables in a higher Cat# keystone jacks, when the versions are NOT backwards-compatable?

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable, gigabit-ethernet, cat6

It is not recommended to use ethernet patch cable in a lower-grade keystone jack (wall outlet), unless there is known backward-compatibility, such as between Cat6 and Cat5e.

Is it acceptable to use ethernet patch cable in a higher-grade keystone jack (wall outlet)?

### Examples:

```
Yes Cat5e cable in Cat5e jack

Yes Cat6  cable in Cat5e jack (due to backward compatability)
Yes Cat6  cable in Cat6  jack 

No  Cat6a cable in Cat5e jack
No  Cat6a cable in Cat6  jack
Yes Cat6a cable in Cat6a jack 

No  Cat8  cable in Cat5e jack
No  Cat8  cable in Cat6  jack
No  Cat8  cable in Cat6a jack
Yes Cat8  cable in Cat8  jack
```

**The question is: Is it okay for:**

```
Cat5e cable in Cat6  jack? (Yes. Backward-compatible, but will be limited to 5e capability.)
Cat5e cable in Cat6a jack?
Cat5e cable in Cat8  jack?

Cat6  cable in Cat6a jack?
Cat6  cable in Cat8  jack?

Cat6a cable in Cat8  jack?
```

### Reference

> It's important to point out here that some categories are backwards compatible with each other. Cat6 cables can be used with Cat5e jacks and Cat5e cables can be used with Cat6 jacks. For Cat6A and above we don't recommend to use the cable on lower category plugs. For example using a Cat8 cable on a Cat6A or Cat5e jack. As well as a Cat6A cable on a Cat5e or Cat6 jack.

[Source](https://infinity-cable-products.com/blogs/connector/how-to-choose-a-keystone-jack).

### Depiction of Cat5e Keystone Jack

[image: Cat5e wall port]

Comment: The connector vs cable mismatch worry for a keystone jack is about the solid bulk cable you punch down to the backside of keystone jack. It's not about what kind of 8P8C male patch cable you plug into the front of it.

Answer (score 3):

For most home purposes, you can treat cat 5, 6 and 7 as compatible, at least experimentally, if you're using Rj45 connectors throughout. Cat 8 is restricted to short runs, 30 m or less, and is for high-speed use, but likely would still function to some extent if used with other grades.

The [differences amongst the cables are internal construction and shielding](https://www.hdcabling.co.za/cat6-vs-cat7-vs-cat8-what-is-the-difference-and-specifications/), not in the number of wires. If a connector is not [exactly the same impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_termination) as the cable, there may be reflections causing reduced transfer rate. That is more of a problem where many devices are connected, such as an office or school; by sticking to tight standards, connectivity is assured. In the home, [it's easy to test](https://www.geckoandfly.com/33225/lan-network-benchmark-test-speed/) the effect on network speed when one additional component is added.